# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1286 Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a website in Laravel 4.2, its been running perfectly fine for months. But since a couple of days, some of my users are complaining about this error:

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1286 Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'**

Sometimes this error appears, sometimes it automatically gets fixed. Right now the website is working fine for me but one of my user is sending me screenshots:

[image]

The strange thing is, this error keeps coming on and off since yesterday. If there really is a syntax error then this error should appear for everyone.

What could be the reason of this error exactly? And how to get rid of it?

Comment: Try restarting your mysql server once.

Comment: And if you got it fixed, put your laravel app from debug to production, your users should never see error messages like this!

Comment: Something bad is happening with InnoDB that makes it basically - die. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and read what's going on. It's difficult to suggest anything without seeing what causes it to go crazy.

Comment: @baao I've intentionally placed the site to debug mode to see what is actually happening. @Mjh the site's hosted on a third party server, where should I run this `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command?

Comment: You should run it in MySQL terminal. It's a query, if you have a tool such as PHPMyAdmin that works too.

Comment: We had same problem. We discovered that mysql user didn't have permission to mysql `tmpdir`. After changing it was fixed. Also found this useful: https://blog.hostonnet.com/mariadb-unknown-storage-engine-innodb